# Problemas con Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un par de preguntas respecto a esta barra hecha con fragmentos. En primer lugar, cuando lo tengo en modo landscape, la barra no se crea hasta el final no adaptándoseme a la vista alargada, dejándome lo siguiente:

[image]

Por tanto, me gustaría que la barra se adaptara, o bien cambiar ese gris por el negro. ¿Dónde puedo cambiarlo? {{Problema solventado}}

El segundo problema me viene al esconder uno de los fragmentos de la barra. La idea es tener un fragmento escondido para que se me cargue como principal, y luego con los otros botones (fragmentos) ir moviéndose. Cuando doy clic al primer elemento de mi barra la animación de hacerse un poco más grande, es decir, la que ocurre al pulsar, que imagino que venga por defecto, en el primer item nunca se me aplica, pero en el resto sí. Si cambio el orden de los items en el xml me ocurre que el pulsar, por ejemplo, llamadas, el efecto ocurre en otro elemento de la barra. Si es muy lioso de cambiar, ¿hay alguna forma de borrar esa animación --al pulsar sobre un elemento de la barra, la letra crece un poco, y por tanto se sube un poco la imagen-- por llamarlo de algún modo.

Tengo los items así:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_abn4"
    android:title="@string/kj4"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/a3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_abnjk"
    android:title="@string/kj3"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/a2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_abn2"
    android:title="@string/kj2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_abn"
    android:title="@string/kj1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:visible="false"
    />
```

Muchas gracias.

EDIT IMÁGENES DEL PROBLEMA 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar tu primer problema debes añadir el siguiente código en el fichero **dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
```

Con esto conseguirás que el bottomNavigation ocupe toda la anchura del dispositivo. Respecto al segundo problema no entiendo muy bien lo que intentas hacer si lo puedes mostrar con alguna imagen para ayudar a entenderlo se agradeceria.

Comment: Mil gracias, he conseguido solucionar lo del primer problema. Respecto al segundo, es en el tema de la barra. Al dar clic a un item de la barra, hay como una especie de animación que hace las letras un pelín más grande, dando el efecto de que se ha pulsado. Pero en un item, ese efecto no se aplica y no sé el porqué, imagino que sea por la posición en la que están colocados, ya que por ejemplo si muevo algún item, ocurre que al dar clic sobre ese item, por ejemplo 'home', el efecto no se aplica sobre 'home' sino otro ítem, pareciendo que se ha pulsado en otro sitio de la pantalla. Edito imágns

Comment: No se que decirte el estilo del pulsado por lo que tengo entendido es igual para todos los botones a menos que lo sobrescribas. Revisa que no hayas añadido algún condicional o algo distinto en styles. Puedes probar de hacer un proyecto a parte a ver si tienes el mismo problema utilizando únicamente el BottomNavigattion.